# getting domain class property value by its String name

Tags: grails, groovy, dns

May be a basic question..
I am doing

```
MyDomain.dirtyPropertyNames.each {
aInstance.oldVal = newDomainObject.getPersistentValue(it)
aInstance.newVal = ? // how to get the property value here from the list obviously MyDomain.it doesnt work..
aInstance.save()
}
```

The dirtyPropertyNames is a list of Property name Strings, how do I get the Domain.property of each property in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does

```
myDomain."$it"
```

Do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the following form for property access through a name.

```
myDomain[it]
```

For instance, if your property name is "lockedFlag" the following are true.

```
assert myDomain.lockedFlag == myDomain["lockedFlag"]
assert myDomain.lockedFlag == myDomain."lockedFlag"
```

I hope this helps.